# Cambiar de clase los botones mediante ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

vengo con un problema que me anda comiendo la cabeza, tengo que hacer que en un modal los botones cambien de color dependiendo de la cantidad de contadores que se encuentran disponibles.
Modelo

```
    public function horario($Fecha){
        try{
            $this->db->query("SELECT Citas_Simultaneas as Citas FROM tarea");
            $citas = $this->db->fetch();
            $this->db->query("SELECT count(*) as Cantidad FROM Citas_Disponibles WHERE TIME(Fecha_Cita) = '09:30' AND DATE(Fecha_Cita)= :Fecha;");
            $this->db->bind(":Fecha", $Fecha);
            $cantidad = $this->db->fetch();
                if ($cantidad->Cantidad > 0 && $cantidad->Cantidad < $citas->Citas )
                {
                    $prueba = 1;
                }else if($cantidad->Cantidad < 1){
                    $prueba = 0;
                }else{
                    $prueba = 2;
            }
            return $prueba;

        }catch(PDOException $Exception){
            error_log($Exception->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Esto lo tengo que hacer por cada media hora desde las 9:30am hasta las 14:00hrs

Controlador

```
    public function horario(){
        $respuestahora = $this->model("feedback");

        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

            $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
            $agendahoras = $this->model('feedback');
            $agendarhorario = $agendahoras->horario($json["Fecha"]);
        }
        response_header();
        echo json_encode(["respuesta"=>$agendarhorario]);

    }
```

Vista (Parte del ajax)

```
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<?php echo PATH_URL; ?>/Sitio/horario',
                data: JSON.stringify({Fecha: info.dateStr}),
                success: function(horario)
                {
                  if(horario.respuesta === 0){
                    $('#nuevetreinta').removeClass('btn-warning');
                    $('#nuevetreinta').removeClass('btn-danger');
                    $('#nuevetreinta').addClass('btn-success');
                    $('#nuevetreinta').prop('disabled', false);
                  }else if(horario.respuesta > 0 && horario.respuesta < 2){
                    $('#nuevetreinta').removeClass('btn-success');
                    $('#nuevetreinta').addClass('btn-warning');
                    $('#nuevetreinta').prop('disabled', false);
                  }else{
                    $('#nuevetreinta').removeClass('btn-success');
                    $('#nuevetreinta').removeClass('btn-warning');
                    $('#nuevetreinta').addClass('btn-danger');
                    $('#nuevetreinta').prop('disabled', true);
                  }
                }
            })
```

Hasta esta parte, hace la comparación en un solo caso, y hace los cambios en un solo botón y pues quisiera saber como puedo recrearlo para varios botones con ese mismo ajax. Saludos.

Comment: Cuales es el caso que si funciona y cual no?

Comment: No entiendo cómo para varios botones. Por lo que entiendo todo tu código funciona. Para recrear en varios botones... ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Quieres que lo hagamos nosotros? Pon el código que no funciona y te apoyamos...

Comment: Oh bueno es que el id "#nuevetreinta" es un solo botón, lo que quiero hacer es que sea por cada id, 
"#nuevetreinta"
"#diez"
"#dieztreinta"
etc.  Lo que intenté es una manera muy burda que es haciendo montón de ajax para hacer las consultas de cada media hora, no se me ocurre otra forma. D: